# Refresh UITableView with prototype cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an UITableView with prototype cells. How to reload it with pull-to-refresh?

Comment: Please learn how to post a proper question.

Comment: A good title would be "how to implement refresh on pull down on a UITableView". On the other hand this are nice works for a search for ready-made answers to the topic. Anyway - how is that related to prototype cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add UIRefreshControll to your app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize Refresh Control
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    // Configure Refresh Control
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    // Configure View Controller
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
}
```

and then something like this:

```
- (void)refresh:(id)sender
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [(UIRefreshControl *)sender endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for pull to refresh, use [STableViewController](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stableviewcontroller)

it is very simple for "pull down to refresh" and also for "more loading".